# Iterate through 2 lists at the same time

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, iterator, java-stream

I am trying to convert the below code to Java 8 (using streams) but not sure how exactly to iterate through 2 lists together using streams.

```
public class ComparisonString {
    private static List<String> input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = Arrays.asList("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","N/A");
        ComparisonString cs = new ComparisonString();
        System.out.println(cs.getMatchedOutput(Arrays.asList("TRUE","N/A","N/A","FALSE")));

    }
    /**
     * Check whether the 'input' List and the 'givenInput' List match.
     * If a value is "N/A" in either lists then it means does-not-matter/don't-check-for-a-match-and-go-next
     * @param givenInput
     * @return
     */
    public Optional<String> getMatchedOutput(final List<String> givenInput) {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenInput.size(); i++) {
            if (this.input.get(i) != null
                    && !(this.input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("N/A")
                    || givenInput.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("N/A"))
                    && !this.input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(givenInput.get(i))) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            return Optional.of("flag = true");
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `IntStream` to generate stream of indexes for both lists, then filter out not relevant list values and match the remaining ones:

```java
public Optional<String> getMatchedOutput(final List<String> givenInput) {
    return IntStream.range(0, givenInput.size())
             .filter(i -> null != input.get(i) && null != givenInput.get(i))
             .filter(i -> !"N/A".equalsIgnoreCase(input.get(i)) && !"N/A".equalsIgnoreCase(givenInput.get(i)))
             .allMatch(i -> input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(givenInput.get(i)))
        ? Optional.of("flag = true")
        : Optional.empty();
}
```

Testing for the known data:

```java
input = Arrays.asList("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","N/A");
ComparisonString cs = new ComparisonString();
 System.out.println(cs.getMatchedOutput(Arrays.asList("TRUE","N/A","N/A","FALSE")));
```

prints:

```
Optional[flag = true]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it and streams is overkill for this and probably less efficient. However, I would make two suggestions:

- no need for a boolean.  Just `return Optional.empty()` immediately upon a failed comparison.  Otherwise, `return Optional.of("flag = true")` after the for loop.
- You should put in a check for unequal `List` sizes. If you choose the longer one for the loop, it could throw an exception.  You could either take the `Math.min` of the two sizes, ignoring the extra elements in the comparison, or just check for equal list sizes and decide what that means in terms of list equality for your application.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't use a stream for manipulating 2 lists at the same time. What you can do is to work with the iterator. I have tried to write some code, it should look something like this:

```java
public static void streamTest(List<String> givenList) {
    List<String> testing = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, givenList.size())
            .parallel()
            .forEach(i -> {
                if (input.get(i) != null
                        && !(input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("N/A")
                        || givenList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("N/A"))
                        && !input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(givenList.get(i)))
                    testing.add("false");
            });
    if (testing.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("flag = true");
    else
        System.out.println("flag = false");
}
```

I hope this helps you and give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible solution that you can use. It looks like `python` `zip` function.

```java
public class ComparisonString {
    private static List<String> input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = Arrays.asList("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "N/A");
        ComparisonString cs = new ComparisonString();
        System.out.println(cs.getMatchedOutput(
                Arrays.asList("TRUE", "N/A", "N/A", "FALSE")));
    }

    public Optional<String> getMatchedOutput(final List<String> givenInput) {
        boolean notFlag = IntStream.range(0, input.size())
                // zip to new object
                .mapToObj(i -> new Pair<>(input.get(i), givenInput.get(i)))

                // stop when the false flag is found
                .anyMatch(p -> {
                    String inputValue = p.getKey();
                    String givenValue = p.getValue();

                    // true breaks the stream
                    return inputValue != null
                            && !("N/A".equalsIgnoreCase(inputValue)
                            || "N/A".equalsIgnoreCase(givenValue))
                            && !inputValue.equalsIgnoreCase(givenValue);
                });
        if (!notFlag) {
            return Optional.of("flag = true");
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Optional[flag = true]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code with [`IntStream#noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) method as follows:

```java
private static List<String> input;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = Arrays.asList("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "N/A");
    System.out.println(
            getMatchedOutput(Arrays.asList("TRUE", "N/A", "N/A", "FALSE")));
}

public static Optional<String> getMatchedOutput(final List<String> givenInput) {
    return IntStream.range(0, givenInput.size()).noneMatch(i ->
            input.get(i) != null
                    && !(input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("N/A")
                    || givenInput.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("N/A"))
                    && !input.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(givenInput.get(i)))
            ? Optional.of("flag = true") : Optional.empty();
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Filter HashMap based on multiple 'optional' conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584984/14940971)</sup>